# Fetch data to React antd table from 2 different API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, antd

I want to use react table and first column data from API-1 and the rest of columns from API-2.
API-1 is the slowest and the column Cells need to be with skeleton until the API-1 data fetched, then the data will be displayed in the first column.

I tried with antd table but no success.

Answer (score 0):

This waits for both apis to respond:

```
const [api1Data, api2Data] = await Promise.all([fetchApi1(), fetchApi2()])
```